# Rotating Polygon Objects

Tags: java, rotation, applet, polygon, trigonometry

## Rotating Asteroids ( Polygons )

I am trying to rotate asteroids(polygons) so that they look nice. I am doing this through multiple mathematical equations. To start I give the individual asteroid a rotation velocity:

```
        rotVel = ((Math.random()-0.5)*Math.PI/16);
```

Then I create the polygon shape,

```
        this.shape = new Polygon();
```

Followed by generating the points,

```
    for (j = 0; j < s; j++) {
        theta = 2 * Math.PI / s * j;
        r = MIN_ROCK_SIZE + (int) (Math.random() * (MAX_ROCK_SIZE - MIN_ROCK_SIZE));
        x = (int) -Math.round(r * Math.sin(theta)) + asteroidData[0];
        y = (int)  Math.round(r * Math.cos(theta)) + asteroidData[1];
        shape.addPoint(x, y);
    }
```

Finally, in a loop a method is being called in which it attempts to move the polygon and its points down as well as rotating them. (I'm just pasting the rotating part as the other one is working)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < shape.npoints; i++) {

       // Subtract asteroid's x and y position
        double x = shape.xpoints[i] - asteroidData[0];
        double y = shape.ypoints[i] - asteroidData[1];

        double temp_x =  ((x * Math.cos(rotVel)) - (y * Math.sin(rotVel)));
        double temp_y =  ((x * Math.sin(rotVel)) + (y * Math.cos(rotVel)));

        shape.xpoints[i] = (int) Math.round(temp_x + asteroidData[0]);
        shape.ypoints[i] = (int) Math.round(temp_y + asteroidData[1]);  
    }
```

now, the problem is that when it prints to the screen the asteroids appear to 'warp' or rather the x and y positions on some of the polygon points 'float' off course.

I've noticed that when I make 'rotVel' be a whole number the problem is solved however the asteroid will rotate at mach speeds. So I've concluded that the problem has to be in the rounding but no matter what I do I can't seem to find a way to get it to work as the Polygon object requires an array of ints.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is definitely caused by rounding to `int`! The first improvement is to make all shape coordinates to be of type `double`. This will solve most of your unwanted 'effects'.

But even with `double` you might experience nasty rounding errors in case you do a lot of very small updates of the coordinates. The solution is simple: Just avoid iterative updates of the asteroid points. Every time, you update the coordinates based on the previous coordinates, the rounding error will get worse.

Instead, add a field for the rotation angle to the shape and increment it instead of the points themselves. Not until drawing the shape, you compute the final positions by applying the rotation to the points. Note that this will never change the points themselves.

You can extend this concept to other transformations (e.g. translation) too. What you get is some kind of local coordinate system for every shape/object. The points of the shape are defined in the local coordinate system. By moving and rotating this system, you can reposition the entire object anywhere in space.

```
public class Shape {
    // rotation and position of the local coordinate system
    private double rot, x, y;

    // points of the shape in local coordinate system
    private double[] xp, yp;
    private int npoints;

    // points of the shape in world coordinates
    private int[][] wxp, wyp;
    private boolean valid;

    public void setRotation(double r) { this.rot = r; valid = false; }
    public void setPosition(double x, double y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; valid = false; }

    public void addPoint(double x, double y) {
        // TODO: add point to xp, yp
        valid = false;
    }

    public void draw(...) {
        if (!valid) {
            computeWorldCoordinates(wxp, wyp);
            valid = true;
        }

        // TODO: draw shape at world coordaintes wxp and wyp
    }

    protected void computeWorldCoordinates(int[] xcoord, int[] ycoord) {
        for (int i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
            double temp_x = xp[i] * Math.cos(rot) - yp[i] * Math.sin(rot);
            double temp_y = xp[i] * Math.sin(rot) + yp[i] * Math.cos(rot);
            xcoord[i] = (int) Math.round(x + temp_x);
            ycoord[i] = (int) Math.round(y + temp_y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your asteroids rotate around (0 , 0) as far as i can see. Correct would be to rotate them around the center of the shape, which would be (n , m), where n is the average of all x-coordinates of the shape, and m is the average of all y-coordinates of the shape.